# Angularjs (ionic) List swipe buttons

Tags: javascript, list, angularjs, button, swipe

I'm working with a list in angularjs with ionic and I want each item swipe to show options.  It's ok through here, but when I tap on one option I want to close the buttons again -- how can i do this in my controller?

```
$scope.listButtons = [{
    Text: "Download",
    Type: "button-assertive",
    onTap: function(file){
        //after tap hide buttons code here..
    }
```

I tried

```
File.hide();
```

And

```
this.hide();
```

But still cannot hide them

Answer (score 1):

You are doing DOM manipulation in the controller. Use directives.

- onTap needs to be a directive, ng-click or similar->
  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick
- jquery .hide() needs to be directive ng-hide->
  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHide

pass the show/hide boolean values via scope from the element that uses ng-click, to the element using ng-hide.

Simple example

```
<button ng-click="listButton.tap=true">{{listButton.Text}}</button>
<button ng-click="listButton.tap=false">{{listButton.Text}} done</button>
<div ng-show="listButton.tap">I am {{listButton.Text}}</div>
<div ng-hide="listButton.tap">I am done {{listButton.Text}}</div>
```

Comment: the button is created by an directive 

    <list can-swipe="true" option-buttons="listButtons">
      <item ng-repeat="file in unrelease" item="file">{{file.name}}</item>
     </list>

Comment: Could you post a plunker or jsfiddle? Need to see example of what you are talking about

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/aIeXw90m64qLeA05zvuM?p=preview when you click on edit or share i want to hide the buttons again. (swipe left and items to see the options buttons)

Comment: In this function onTap-> rather than using "this.hide()", attach a boolean value to object item to show/hide. For each '<div class="item'  element add the directive ng-hide that will take this boolean value

Comment: I don't want to hide the entire item, just close the swiped options only

Comment: then add the ng-hide directive or directives to these elements you refer to